# Unable to install Homebrew in mac using ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory, ansible-template

Trying  to install Home brew on mac by ansible , but getting the error. Please help me to fix the issue.

```
- name: Install Homebrew on mac
  hosts: mac_vms
  tasks: 
    - name: Check if Homebrew is already installed
      stat:
        path: /usr/local/bin/brew
      register: b
    - name: Execute the script
      shell: /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/.../master/install.sh)"
      delay: 3
      when: not b.stat.exists
```

**Getting below error**

```
    enter code here

 "stdout": "Warning: Running in non-interactive mode because `stdin` is not a TTY.\n==> Checking for `sudo` access (which may request your password)...",
    "stdout_lines": [
        "Warning: Running in non-interactive mode because `stdin` is not a TTY.",
        "==> Checking for `sudo` access (which may request your password)..."
```

**Installation command :**

```
ansible-playbook -i hosts.yaml installHomeBrew.yml -vvvv -b -K
```

Comment: The message seems pretty clear, does it not? You need to configure `sudo` in `NOPASSWD:` mode to allow that script to elevate privileges (which is different from `become: true` because I believe their install script will not allow running as root)

Comment: How to configure NOPASSWD  from ansible?  I am new to ansible, please share any link

Comment: Well, what have you already tried? What outcome is it producing for you? Does that mean you have not yet read [`man sudoers`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man5/sudoers.5.html#examples)?

Comment: @mdaniel. its working ,Thanks 
And another doubt , i am trying to get conda info by shell or command, but  for both output printing as "$(conda info)".


shell: echo $(conda info) 
command : echo $(conda info)